# React native - rerender only part of a parent component (performance issue)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-component

I have the following hierarchy:

```
Home
 ⎿ setSnackText (use state hook) 
 ⎿ MyQuestionsList
    ⎿ MySingleQuestion(setSnackText) (onClick -> props.setSnackText(this.text)
 ⎿ MySnackBar
```

I want the snackbar visibility/text to be accessible for each child element and it wroks fine by passing the setSnackText function to each child element with props

But the **problem** is that on each setSnackText (hook) invokation, the whole component (Home) including the list are now forced to be rerender which causes performance issues.

Here is my code:

**Home:**

```
const ViewSingleSheet = (props) => {
const [questionNote, setQuestionNote] = useState(null);
return (
            <Block flex stretch style={styles.home}>
                <Block style={styles.sheetDetails}>
                    <Block>

                    </Block>
                </Block>
                <Block style={styles.questionContainer}>
                    <FlatList data={questions}
                        initialNumToRender={200}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => {
                            return <SingleQuestion setQuestionNote={setQuestionNote} question={item}></SingleQuestion>
                        }}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    />
                </Block>
            </Block>
        );
```

}

**SingleQuestion:**

```
const SingleQuestion = (props) => {
return (<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => props.setQuestionNote('some notes....')}>
                <FontAwesome5 name={"info-circle"} size={19}></FontAwesome5>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>);
}
```

Any workaround?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @MahdiN Just did

Answer (score 0):

If certain child components don't need to rerender if they will receive the same props, you can wrap them in `React.memo`, for example:

```
Home
 ⎿ setSnackText (use state hook) 
 ⎿ MyList
    ⎿ React.memo(MyItem(setSnackText)) (onClick -> props.setSnackText(this.text)
 ⎿ React.memo(MySnackBar)
```

However, rerendering rarely causes noticeable performance issues; React just executes the components and checks if the elements that they return are different from the previous render. If the elements match, it won't change the DOM, which is the expensive part. Most of the time you don't need to worry about micro-optimizations.

Comment: It's actually, there is around 1 second of laggy screen on each change text invokation.
My FlatList contains around 100 complex items.

Comment: just tried it and it didn't work :( , I even added a second parameter to memo [(prev, next) => { return true }] as fake function to explicitly force not to render but it keeps rendering (I added a console.log in the list functional component)